# Telegram bot Python bottom "back"?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

We need such a button so that even if the bot breaks, the button works. Is it possible?

We are making a bot in aiogram. Of course, we can make a back button through the list, but if the bot breaks, the back button will not work. The bot literally restarts.